# VxWorks initiating connect() it fails at startup, but succeeds later

Tags: c, tcp, vxworks

I'm using VxWorks 5.4 and attempting to connect to a server via TCP. A server which I'm going to be sending logs to, but for some reason at boot it fails or takes even up to 6 seconds - and is blocking the continuation of the task that the connection attempt was made in, which obviously is a big no no.

I have checked if the problem is one the server side by making a simple c program in windows that would connect to that server, and it takes no time at all (milliseconds).

I have "solved" the problem by making a task that would attempt "connectwithtineout" every 1-2 seconds and it does work (initiates the connection after around 2 fails in around 20ms), but I don't really like this approach and would have liked to initiate the actual connection when whatever I need that I'm missing is there and up instead of checking if I can connect every time.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you've made a service that starts at boot? Have you made it dependant on the networking service (whatever that's called in vxworks)?

Comment: I have made a task, that attempts connection and has a timeout of 2 seconds everytime, once the connection is established i start another task, and this one dies. Nothing special regarding the networking device that ive put into my code (except for routing to a different net using netrouteadd)

Comment: But, do you check that the needed networking services are all up before you start your task?

Comment: No, that is exactly what I'm looking for, realize what those might be. Are they card specific?

Comment: I think I found something about it might being driver implementation specific, I'm now looking into this, still would love any insight you might have on this

Comment: I have done as I said, and yet couldn't find any solution to this, would love a hint on this where I should go look

Comment: I would look at what dependencies other services that are usually started at boot depend on. `sshd`, `apache`, `smtpd` etc. They probably have some dependency in common. Add the same dependency for your task.

Comment: Nothing of the sorty have i found on my system. VxWorks headers/ BSP/ App

Comment: How is your task started? It sounds like it's started before all the services needed are properly up an running. *nix-like systems usually have some dependency chain specified so that one service depends on another service before it's started etc. Even if you don't call it a service, you have a similar dependency.

Comment: VxWorks + drivers related stuff -> initialize main app  task-> initialize connection to a log server (where my issue lies) -> initialize various tasks like error handling/ general task for running main task.
The service that you are mentioning is exactly what im looking for, and im trying to figure out if there is some field that i can use to do an "if" statement upon.

Comment: Ok, perhaps looking at how your DLT daemon(s) make sure everything is in order at startup can help?

Comment: Is this a shell command/ some c code I'm supposed to write or some VxWorks library that I can use? I'm not at work currently so I have no access

Comment: It'll depend a little on what you have done here: [Choosing a Systems and Services Init Manager](https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_Linux_Platform_Developers_Guide_LTS_18_1/page/qli1472852672645.html) but usually, it's just a matter of putting your dependencies in a config file.

Comment: I fixed it a while ago, came back to explain what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

After trying to investigate what the issue could have been, eventually the problem was about how a session is being closed between my system and the server.

You see, when you have a client running on some app on your windows/ or whatever other system, when you shut it down, it goes through some processes that close the session properly.

That is not the case in my system where to close it I essentially unplug the wire - thereby not having my system go through a shutdown process that involves properly closing the session.

After the system is up again, the connect function cannot be performed because my system tries to make the same session as the "dead one" which the server thinks is running.

Solving the problem was easy from the server side, just have a keepalive functionality - if your system doesn't respond for a while that you decide, close the session.